# how to check number exists between braces

Tags: java, logic

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckValidLocationofParenthensies {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter five data");
            String input1 = scanner.next();

     balancedParenthensies(input1);

    }

    public static boolean balancedParenthensies(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{' ) { 
             stack.push(c);
             if(c == '[') {
                 newvalueforforward(s,']', i);
            }
            if(c == '{') {
                newvalueforforward(s,'}', i);
            }
            if(c == '(') {
                newvalueforforward(s,')', i);
            }

            } else if(c == ']') {
                if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '[') {
                    newvalue(s,'[', i);
                    return false;
                }
            } else if(c == ')') {
                if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') {
                    newvalue(s,'(', i);
                 return false;
                }           
            } else if(c == '}') {
                if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '{') {
                    newvalue(s,'{', i);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void newvalueforforward(String userval,char value,int decremntval) {

         for(int i = 0; i < userval.length(); i++){

             StringBuilder newvalue = new StringBuilder(userval);

            int location=i;
             newvalue.insert(i, value);

             boolean valid= checkingnewvalueisValidorNot(newvalue, location);
             location=i+1;
             if(valid) {
                System.out.println(newvalue+"   "+""+location); 

             }

        }

    }

 public static void newvalue(String userval,char value,int decremntval) {


        for(int i = decremntval; i >= 0; i--){

             StringBuilder newvalue = new StringBuilder(userval);
            int location=decremntval - i;
             newvalue.insert(decremntval - i, value);

             boolean valid= checkingnewvalueisValidorNot(newvalue, location);

             if(valid) {
                 System.out.println(newvalue+"   "+""+location); 

             }

        }

    }



public static boolean checkingnewvalueisValidorNot(StringBuilder userval,int validpath) {

     Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();
     for(int i = 0; i < userval.length(); i++) {
         char c = userval.charAt(i);
         if(c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{' ) { 

             stack.push(c);
         } else if(c == ']') {
             if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '[') {
                 return false;
             }
         } else if(c == ')') {
             if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') {            
                 return false;
             }           
         } else if(c == '}') {
             if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '{') {
               return false;
             }
         }

     }
     return stack.isEmpty();

    }


}
```

Above is the code i have written to check whether input string contains all balanced brackets if it is not balanced then get missing bracket and place bracket in all index then again check whether string is balanced or not.

I got valid output but problem is between i bracket there should be a intergers

here is input and outputs

```
input         missing     outputs
{[(2+3)*6/10}   ]   {[](2+3)*6/10}   3 not valid(no numbres btn bracket)
                    {[(2+3)]*6/10}   8 valid
                    {[(2+3)*]6/10}   9   not valid(after * no number)
                    {[(2+3)*6]/10}   10  valid
                    {[(2+3)*6/]10}   11 not valid( / before bracket)
                    {[(2+3)*6/1]0}   12 not valid( / btn num bracket)
                    {[(2+3)*6/10]}   13 valid
```

i am failing to do proper validation to my output.

Comment: You may want to study "context free grammars" and how to build parsers for them.

Answer (score 0):

Before the bracket there may be:

- number
- closing bracket

After the bracket there may be:

- operator
- closing bracket
- end of expression

(ignoring any whitespace)

Comment: yes that's correct but i am failing to write logic for it

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number exists between braces, you can modify the checkingnewvalueisValidorNot() method in the given code as follows:

```java
public static boolean checkingnewvalueisValidorNot(StringBuilder userval, int validpath) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    boolean isNumEnclosed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < userval.length(); i++) {
        char c = userval.charAt(i);
        if (c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{') {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (c == ']') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '[') {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (c == '}') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '{') {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c) && !stack.isEmpty()) {
            isNumEnclosed = true;
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty() && isNumEnclosed;
}
```

This modified method adds a boolean variable isNumEnclosed that becomes true if a digit is found and there is an opening brace in the stack. It returns true only if the stack is empty and isNumEnclosed is true, which means there is a digit enclosed by braces in the string.